# Textarea for Javascript language with autocomplete and syntax highlighting

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete, syntax-highlighting

I have found it before, a textarea for javascript with autocomplete and syntax highlighting.
but i forgot what is the name of the component, i have googled it but not yet found any luck.

it's not:

- editarea
- bespin
- not an online IDE (cloud9, etc)
- SyntaxHighlighter
- CodeMirror
- CodePress

similar to this one: http://esprima.org/demo/autocomplete.html

Answer (score 1):

Check if this suits your needs

[codemirror.net](http://codemirror.net/mode/javascript/index.html)

Except if you are looking for a  wysiwyg editor with javascript autocomplete and syntax highlighting. If thats the case the closest to that must be

[tinymce.com](http://www.tinymce.com/)

Comment: nope not codemirror and not a wysiwyg editor, just a javascript source code editor with awesome autocomplet, i just forgot the name >__<

Comment: You can always check your browser history to find it out :d

Comment: XD yes, but my browsing history is somehow a mess.. XD too many links that i have opened each day..